# PHP doesn't insert in SQL Table even if there aren't error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-insert

I am working with the ip information of who visits an html page. I don't want to use GeoIp etc: I'm going to use ipinfo.io service. At the end of html page I did a get function, and inside it I wrote the ajax post.

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
var ip = response.ip;
var hostname = response.hostname;
var city = response.city;
var region = response.region;
var country = response.country;
var loc = response.loc;
var org = response.org;
var postal = response.postal;
var details = JSON.stringify(response, null, 4); 

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'write.php', 
    data: '&ip=' + ip + '&hostname=' + hostname +'&city=' + city +  '&region=' + region +  '&country=' + country +  '&loc=' + loc +  '&org=' + org +  '&postal=' + postal +  '&details=' + details,
    success: function (data) {   
      alert("Sent");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, text, error){ 
       alert("Error: not sent.");       
      }
  }); 

}, "jsonp");
```

I was inspired by this: http://jsfiddle.net/zk5fn/2/

In the write.php I've written some fwrite method that wrote all the data taken. And it works. Now, I wanted to post these data in a database. I've create one with phpmyadmin with 000webhost.

I display no error in the post, but where I open phpmyadmin the table is empty... why?
This is the word.php:

```
<?php 

 $link =  mysql_connect("localhost", "name......", "psw....", "database-name");   

if (!$link) {
    alert('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo 'Connected successfully';

// Parse input
$ip      = $_POST['ip'];
$hostname    = $_POST['hostname'];
$city    = $_POST['city'];
$region  = $_POST['region'];
$country  = $_POST['country'];
$loc  = $_POST['loc'];
$org  = $_POST['org'];
$postal  = $_POST['postal'];
$details  = $_POST['details'];

$sql="insert into `sessions` (ip, hostname, city, region,country, loc, org, postal) values('$ip','$hostname', '$city', '$region', '$country', '$loc', '$org' ,'$postal')";  

    $res = mysql_query($sql); 



if($res){

    echo "Records added successfully.";

}   

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

**UPDATE** 
This is the log of the post:
[image]

**UPDATE 2** 
This is the SQL seen when I click for export the database:

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
`id` int(128) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ip` varchar(128) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`hostname` varchar(128) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`city` varchar(128) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`region` varchar(128) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`country` varchar(128) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`loc` varchar(128) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`org` varchar(128) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`postal` varchar(128) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci     AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Does it actually echo "Records added successfully." to the screen?

Comment: add "or die (mysqli_error());"  at the end of your query to see whats the error

Comment: This code is unsafe and exposed to sql injection attack

Comment: Echo $sql after you define it to see if the values are even present in the query. I've never seen POST data passed that way; is that possible? I usually use objects {ip:ipVar, host:hostVar}. Also look into sanitizing or prepared statements to prevent sql injection.

Comment: `mysql_connect("localhost", "name......", "psw....", "database-name")` that doesn't do what you *wish/hope* it should.

Comment: @mark.hch I can't see that echo. @ rhopercy I added that string but I don't see any error. @ Alon i know it is not safe, i'm trying to learning better php! @ fred ofcourse in my php file i've written the real data... I wrote "name......" just for see that over there i wrote the user name of the phpmyadmin

Comment: `mysql_connect` => http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php `$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');` 3 parameters, not 4. *That's, what I was talking about*. ;-)

Comment: è tre parametri, non è quattro mi amico ^

Comment: ahahaha parli italiano? :D anyway, I thought it was the database name... so that is wrong?

Comment: si, parlo la lingua ;-) e si, non bene. quattro parametri è per `mysqli_` e no `mysql_`. ha bisognare tre parametri é utilizare `mysql_select_db` con `mysql_`.

Comment: Grande! But i've found the real problem: simply 000webhost don't permit to modify the table with external code (as in my case)

Comment: ah yes; of course. remote connection not allowed. oh well, least you found *il problema*. salute! *ciao*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this JS code:

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
  var ip = response.ip;
  var hostname = response.hostname;
  var city = response.city;
  var region = response.region;
  var country = response.country;
  var loc = response.loc;
  var org = response.org;
  var postal = response.postal;
  var details = JSON.stringify(response, null, 4); 

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'write.php', 
    data: 'ip=' + ip + '&hostname=' + hostname +'&city=' + city +  '&region=' + region +  '&country=' + country +  '&loc=' + loc +  '&org=' + org +  '&postal=' + postal +  '&details=' + details,
    success: function (data) {   
      console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, text, error){ 
        console.log(text);
    }
  }); 

}, "jsonp");
```

And this PHP code:

```
$link =  mysql_connect("localhost", "name......", "psw....", "database-name");   

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

print("This is what was received: ");
print("\r\n");
print_r($_POST);
print("\r\n");

// Parse input
$ip = $_POST['ip'];
$hostname = $_POST['hostname'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$region = $_POST['region'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$loc = $_POST['loc'];
$org = $_POST['org'];
$postal = $_POST['postal'];
$details = $_POST['details'];

$sql = "insert into `sessions` (ip, hostname, city, region,country, loc, org, postal) values('$ip','$hostname', '$city', '$region', '$country', '$loc', '$org' ,'$postal')";

print("This is what is sending to database: \"$sql\"");
print("\r\n");

$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 

if($res){
    print("Records added successfully.");
}   

mysql_close($link);
die();
```

After this open the web browser developer tools on *console* section and see what happens.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/483gnyazx/

Comment: Ding! Read the second line: Access denied for user ...

This is the error.

Comment: Yeah I've read it, but lol the credential are right..... the user to login to the database is a6033757_admin and I wrote it in the mysql_connect... maybe i have to add @localhost?

Comment: Has 2 possibilities: 1) The password is wrong or 2) the user has no privileges to access mysql server/database.

Comment: As I can see this error is in your development mode. Certify that this user has right permissions in desired database. In example of Hostgator, you must to create database, assing an user and set their permissions (create, select, delete...)

Comment: in phpmyadmin I login with the same crendtial...it is the unique account and in phpmyadmin window i can add remove etc... maybe i can't write from external file? I don't know... that stupid 000webhost let me just give the possibilty to change the password of the users, the privileges are not mentioned

Comment: you were just right, i've changed host (altervista) and now it works......!!! Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

I would change `$res = mysql_query($sql);` to `$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` to learn more about possible errors on your insert query. Also you should apply mysql_real_escape_string to any data you're inserting into your database.

Comment: It doesn't show any error :/ Anyway, I should define the variables like so: $hostname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hostname']); ?

Comment: I would double check your field names in your database interface (such as phpMyAdmin) to ensure you referenced them correctly in your php code. Also, yes that is the correct way to escape your post variables.

Comment: If you see my answer, i've update it with code sql code

Answer (score 0):

if you debug the PHP code, what has in $_POST? Try this:

```
$received = print_r($_POST, true);
$file = fopen('log.txt', 'w+');
fwrite($file, $received);
fclose($file);
```

After this, validade what the PHP is receiving, if need, paste here to us can help you.

I don't try but I think the error is on `data: '&ip=' + ip ...`. As this is the first key the `&` is unnecessary. Try to debug as I explaned and see what it is sending via ajax to PHP.

Comment: Adding you code, I have no error in Console of firefox, but I can't see any new log.txt file!!

Comment: Ok, this is because the PHP is receiving the $_POST and writing its contents in a file. Check in the same path of your *write.php* if exists the file *log.txt*, open it and see what was written.

Comment: Yeah I've look there, but that file doesn't exist!

Comment: Ok, I'll post another answer soon to you to try.

Comment: Thanksss, and I still  try to solve too

Comment: I've update my answer with the log of the post

Answer (score 0):

I would advise the following PHP that uses MySQLi Prepared Statement:

```
<?php 
$link =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "name......", "psw....", "database-name");   
$error = false;

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    $error = mysqli_connection_error();
    echo "Connection Error: $error"; 
    exit();
} else {
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO sessions (ip, hostname, city, region, country, loc, org, postal) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param(
            $stmt,
            "ssssssss",
            $_POST['ip'],
            $_POST['hostname'],
            $_POST['city'],
            $_POST['region'],
            $_POST['country'],
            $_POST['loc'],
            $_POST['org'],
            $_POST['postal'],
            $_POST['details']
        );
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        echo "Records added successfully.";
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

MySQL extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.

Then in your `success`, you can do something like:

```
success: function (data) {   
  if(data.indexOf("Error")){
    console.error(data);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: mmmm.... I've modify my code with your and this is the console result in html file: http://postimg.org/image/tazhlcqid/

Comment: @panagulis72 The first error shows a login failure. The second part is that you are mixing `mysql` with `mysqli` and you cannot do that. Please make sure your code is correct as well as your MySQL Credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the host with altervista. NOW IT WORKS.... I've spent 1 day for nothing.... damn! So, for who will have this problem, just don't choose 000webhost. Because with it you can create db, but you can't delete/add/modify anything using external file.